# String read from file appears different than the text written to the file -Android

Tags: android, string, file-io

---

**SOLVED: SEE BELOW**

I'm trying to save some data to a file, so later I can access them.

However, when I write the string, and read it, then it looks good. But when I try to read from the file and display it on a `Toast` it doesn't show good. 
The text is full of spaces.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    fos = openFileOutput("1"+i, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
    text =  "{id"+ "1"+ i + "id}"+
            "{amount" + Amount + "amount}"+
            "{category"+ category + "category}"+
            "{date"+ date.getText() + "date}"+
            "{description"+ description.getText() + "description}";
    dos.writeChars(text);
    dos.close();
    fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The second activity, when it opens fires this code:

```
        try {
    FileInputStream fis;
    fis = openFileInput("11");
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            dis.readUTF(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dis.close();
    fis.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When the toast shows, the text looks something like this:

{ i d 1 1 i d } ...

---

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Instead of using 
`dos.writeChars(text);`

I use: `dos.writeUTF(text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read in UTF you should make sure to also write in UTF

Comment: Yes, I just saw my mistake. Thanks for replying.